# How to come back to single cursor mode in Visual Studio Code

Tags: visual-studio-code, keyboard-shortcuts

In Visual Studio it is possible to place the cursor on multiple lines in order to edit them in *parallel*. On my OS (Ubuntu), the shortcut to enable the multi-cursors mode is <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Up</kbd> or 
<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Down</kbd>.

Is there a shortcut to come back to the single-cursor mode?

On the [official documentation](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/keybindings) there is nothing on this feature, neither for activation, nor for deactivation. In order to make this question as more general as possible, since Visual Code's shortcuts are OS-dependent, I'm looking for an answer covering all the major OS.

Comment: Try hitting Esc, see if that does it.

Comment: No, it doesn't work

Comment: If Esc didn't work for you, how is your selected answer (which is written by you) to press Esc?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I answer my own question.

Apparently, in the current version of Visual Code, it is sufficient to press `Esc` to come back to the single cursor mode.

Comment: Someone else answered this when the question was asked. I believe it would be proper to give them the credit.

Comment: When the comment was posted, I tried and it didn't work. Now i noticed that it works, and I guess it was just a minor bug fixed in one of the updates released from october '18 up to now.

Answer (score 8):

I am not on linux, but it should be `escape`, which is bound to Command `workbench.action.terminal.clearSelection`.

You can check this in `Keymap Shortcuts`

```
{
  "key": "escape",
  "command": "workbench.action.terminal.clearSelection",
  "when": "terminalFocus && terminalTextSelected && !terminalFindWidgetVisible"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In Windows pressing **ALT** key twice will work fine, I hope pressing **Option** key twice will work in Mac OS. Thank You! :)